# Add options from Pop-Up to Table

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I'm in the process of creating a timetable. If I click on a
Tables, a pop-up window will open in which the individual subjects are included. If I select an option from there, the pop-up window should close and the selected option should be entered in the table.

## HTML

```
<div class="popup-table">
        <div class="popup-window">
            <div class="close-popup" onclick="closingPopUp()">
                <h4>X</h4>
            </div>
            <p class="options">Deu</p>
            <p class="options">Eng</p>
            <p class="options">Mat</p>
            <p class="options">Erd</p>
            <p class="options">Ges</p>
            <p class="options">Mus</p>
            <p class="options">Kun</p>
            <p class="options">Spo</p>
            <p class="options">Che</p>
            <p class="options">Phy</p>
            <p class="options">Bio</p>
            <p class="options">Fra</p>
            <p class="options">Spa</p>
            <p class="options">Pol</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row headline">
            <p>Std</p>
            <p>Mo</p>
            <p>Di</p>
            <p>Mi</p>
            <p>Do</p>
            <p>Fr</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row extra">
            <p>1</p>
            <p id="selectText" onclick="openPopUp()"></p>
            <p onclick="openPopUp()"></p>
            <p onclick="openPopUp()"></p>
            <p onclick="openPopUp()"></p>
            <p onclick="openPopUp()"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p>2</p>
            <p onclick="openPopUp()"></p>
            <p onclick="openPopUp()"></p>
            <p onclick="openPopUp()"></p>
            <p onclick="openPopUp()"></p>
            <p onclick="openPopUp()"></p>
        </div>
```

## JavaScript

```
let row = document.querySelectorAll(".row");
let popUp = document.querySelector(".popup-table");
let closePopUp = document.querySelector(".close-popup");
let options = document.getElementsByClassName("options");
let selectText = document.getElementById("selectText");

function openPopUp() {
    popUp.classList.add("show")
}

function closingPopUp() {
    popUp.classList.remove("show")
}

for(option of options){
    option.onclick = function(){
        selectText.innerHTML = this.textContent;
        closingPopUp();
    }
}
```

The whole thing only works if I assign an Id and not on a Class. But I can only change this one table field.

Maybe someone can help me make this work and I can make a selection individually in each table field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cache the currently active element, please see the example:

```js
let row = document.querySelectorAll(".row");
let popUp = document.querySelector(".popup-window");
let closePopUp = document.querySelector(".close-popup");
let options = document.getElementsByClassName("options");
let activeElement;

function openPopUp(element) {
    popUp.classList.add("show");
    activeElement = element;
}

function closingPopUp() {
    popUp.classList.remove("show");
}

for(option of options){
    option.onclick = function(){
        activeElement.innerHTML = this.textContent;
        closingPopUp();
    }
}
```

```css
.popup-window {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  gap: 1em;
  background-color: white;
}

td {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-table">
        <div class="popup-window">
            <div class="close-popup" onclick="closingPopUp()">
                <h4>X</h4>
            </div>
            <p class="options">Deu</p>
            <p class="options">Eng</p>
            <p class="options">Mat</p>
            <p class="options">Erd</p>
            <p class="options">Ges</p>
            <p class="options">Mus</p>
            <p class="options">Kun</p>
            <p class="options">Spo</p>
            <p class="options">Che</p>
            <p class="options">Phy</p>
            <p class="options">Bio</p>
            <p class="options">Fra</p>
            <p class="options">Spa</p>
            <p class="options">Pol</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="row headline">
            <th>Std</th>
            <th>Mo</th>
            <th>Di</th>
            <th>Mi</th>
            <th>Do</th>
            <th>Fr</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row extra">
            <td>1</td>
            <td onclick="openPopUp(this)"></td>
            <td onclick="openPopUp(this)"></td>
            <td onclick="openPopUp(this)"></td>
            <td onclick="openPopUp(this)"></td>
            <td onclick="openPopUp(this)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td>2</td>
            <td onclick="openPopUp(this)"></td>
            <td onclick="openPopUp(this)"></td>
            <td onclick="openPopUp(this)"></td>
            <td onclick="openPopUp(this)"></td>
            <td onclick="openPopUp(this)"></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked :) Can you maybe give me a tip on what I have to do if I write the pop-up options longer and want to limit them to 3 letters in the table!? Can I do this with "slice"?

Comment: Yes, you could do `activeElement.innerHTML = this.textContent.slice(0, 3)` or `activeElement.innerHTML = this.textContent.substring(0, 3)`. Or if you want to use abbreviations that are not the first 3 chars, you can add a data attribute to the options `<p class="options" data-abbr="DE">Deutsch</p>` and use it like `activeElement.innerHTML = this.dataset.abbr`.

Answer (score 1):

To make your code work for multiple table fields, you can use the `event.target` property to get the element that was clicked on. You can then use the `id` or `class` of that element to determine which table field to update.

Here is a modified version of your code that works for multiple table fields:

```html
<div class="popup-table">
  <div class="popup-window">
    <div class="close-popup" onclick="closingPopUp()">
      <h4>X</h4>
    </div>
    <p class="options">Deu</p>
    <p class="options">Eng</p>
    <p class="options">Mat</p>
    <p class="options">Erd</p>
    <p class="options">Ges</p>
    <p class="options">Mus</p>
    <p class="options">Kun</p>
    <p class="options">Spo</p>
    <p class="options">Che</p>
    <p class="options">Phy</p>
    <p class="options">Bio</p>
    <p class="options">Fra</p>
    <p class="options">Spa</p>
    <p class="options">Pol</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table">
  <div class="row headline">
    <p>Std</p>
    <p>Mo</p>
    <p>Di</p>
    <p>Mi</p>
    <p>Do</p>
    <p>Fr</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row extra">
    <p>1</p>
    <p id="selectText1" onclick="openPopUp(this)"></p>
    <p id="selectText2" onclick="openPopUp(this)"></p>
    <p id="selectText3" onclick="openPopUp(this)"></p>
    <p id="selectText4" onclick="openPopUp(this)"></p>
    <p id="selectText5" onclick="openPopUp(this)"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>2</p>
    <p id="selectText6" onclick="openPopUp(this)"></p>
    <p id="selectText7" onclick="openPopUp(this)"></p>
    <p id="selectText8" onclick="openPopUp(this)"></p>
    <p id="selectText9" onclick="openPopUp(this)"></p>
    <p id="selectText10" onclick="openPopUp(this)"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
let popUp = document.querySelector(".popup-table");
let closePopUp = document.querySelector(".close-popup");
let options = document.getElementsByClassName("options");

function openPopUp(element) {
  popUp.classList.add("show");
  // Store the element that was clicked on so that we can update it later.
  this.clickedElement = element;
}

function closingPopUp() {
  popUp.classList.remove("show");
}

for (option of options) {
  option.onclick = function () {
    // Get the element that was clicked on.
    const clickedElement = this.clickedElement;

    // Update the innerHTML of the clicked element.
    clickedElement.innerHTML = this.textContent;

    // Close the pop-up window.
    closingPopUp();
  };
}
```

This code works by passing the element that was clicked on to the `openPopUp()` function. The `openPopUp()` function stores this element in a property called `clickedElement`. When the user clicks on an option in the pop-up window, the `closingPopUp()` function is called. This function updates the innerHTML of the `clickedElement` with the text of the option that was clicked on. It then closes the pop-up window.

You can use this same approach to update any table field, regardless of whether it has an ID or a class.